# Constraint change animation not working on iOS7

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I'm animating the change of an NSLayoutContraint to slide in a view from the top edge of the screen. I already found answers how to do this properly and it works perfectly fine in iOS8. However if I try the same code on iOS7 it just doesn't slide in my view but the view just stays at the same place instead.

Here's my code:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

if (_filterVisible) {
    [_filterViewTopConstraint setConstant:-_filterViewHeight.constant];
    _filterVisible = NO;
}else{
    [_filterViewTopConstraint setConstant:0];
    _filterVisible = YES;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

The constants for the layout constraints have the right values, I already checked that.
Has anybody experienced a similar issue or can help me with this?

Comment: The code looks fine. Maybe you could debug and print out the value for `_filterViewHeight`? Maybe that one is nil or 0 on iOS 7

Comment: I just debugged it. The constant for _filterViewHeight is 200 (just like I specified it) for both iOS8 and iOS7.

Comment: Try changing the `y` value of the frame too along with the change in constraint constant.

Comment: sometime it's necessary to call `[yourAnimView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` before to animate the contraint

Comment: I also tried to do this but without any luck.

Comment: @OutOfBounds : did u find any solution ?

Comment: @BishalGhimire: no, i used some workaround which are far from optimal